# joomla users admin

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

In the joomla users admin when a users data is loaded, where is the function to call the users data

administrator/components/com_users/models/user.php

```
$result = parent::getItem($pk);
```

This is the code that returns the data, but I need to find where this function is? I want to amend the query as I've added some form fields, but I need to know which parent, as there are many getItem functions in Joomla

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla 1.7 provides a mechanism ( http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin ) for adding extra fields through user plugins. This is a far more robust method than editing core files - for one thing edits to core files risk being overwritten as soon as you update and as updating is a simple push button affair it is likely to be sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

found it libraries/joomla/application/component/modeladmin.php